# Java Compare Vertex Lexicographically

Tags: java

We're doing an assignment where it compares the weight of different edges, returning true or false and I just need someone to explain the teacher's code here

```
boolean thisTest;

int small = (thisTest = u < v) ? u : v,
big = (thisTest) ? v : u;
```

Could someone just explain the operation here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's equivalent to :

```
if u < v 
   thisTest = true
else 
    thisTest = false

if(thisTest)
  small = u;
else
  small = v;

if(thisTest)
  big = v;
else
  big = u;
```

If we look closely :

```
int small = (thisTest = u < v) ? u : v;
```

`(thisTest = u < v)` is evaluated first. So if `u < v`, `thisTest = true` else `thisTest = false`.

So you have :

```
boolean thisTest = u < v;
int small = thisTest ? u : v; //ternary operator, if thisTest is true then small = u else small = v
big = thisTest ? v : u; //same reason, if thisTest is true, then big = v else big = u
```

To summarize, `small` will contain the smallest value between `u` and `v` and `big` will contain the largest. If `u == v`, `big` and `small` will have the same value.

You can have more informations [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) :

> Another conditional operator is ?:, which can be thought of as
>   shorthand for an if-then-else statement (discussed in the Control Flow
>   Statements section of this lesson). This operator is also known as the
>   ternary operator because it uses three operands.

Comment: Same discussion as before: change habit and call it *Conditional Operator* :)